# Command to display active conda channels

Tags: python, conda

Is there a command to display active `conda` channels?

I know I can search for the `.condarc` file to check for any added channels. However, there are two problems with this approach:

1. The default channels might change on newer version of `conda`. For example, since *conda 4.7*, the `free` channel has been removed from the default channels. Another example is the addition of channel `main` in *conda 4.3.27*.
2. No unified way to display channels (that is open file contents) in different OS.

Therefore, a command is necessary for viewing active `conda` channels. Does such a command exist? I have conducted a web search, but have I have not found something.

Answer (score 69):

In addition to `conda info`, one can also query configuration info specifically with the `conda config --show [key]` command.  For high-level channel names, one can use

```
conda config --show channels
```

which outputs what you'd see in the `.condarc`, i.e., just the names of the channels, no URLs.  The URLs used in `defaults` can be queried separately,

```
conda config --show default_channels
```

which for me gives,

```
default_channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
```

Answer (score 13):

By executing:

```
conda info
```

It displays information about `conda`, including current channels. More specifically, it displays the URL of the channels. For example, the channels listed in a freshly installed `conda` environment using default `conda` settings in an *Ubuntu 16.04 64bit OS* are:

```
channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

You can distinguish the channel name from the URLs. In the above example, the channels listed are `main` and `r`.